# ffmpeg hstack png and replace transparent color with white color

Tags: ffmpeg

Below command works fine to stack two png file with alpha channel left and right, The output png file will keep the alpha channel as well.

```
ffmpeg -i a.png -i b.png -filter_complex hstack=inputs=2 output.png
```

I wish replace alpha channel with white color (no need alpha channel), which parameter should I use?

Comment: `hstack=inputs=2,format=rgb24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this filter:

```
color=c=white[b];\
hstack=inputs=2[f];\
[b][f]scale2ref[b1][f1];\
[b1][f1]overlay
```

also set `-pix_fmt rgb24` output option

Comment: Thanks, I got below error: [image2 @ 0x1b2ce20] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'output.png' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument

Comment: try adding `-vframes 1` output option